# Jquery add property values to css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm new to jquery. I just want to do a task on drop-down menu as below:

```
if (scrnwidth <= 761) {
        if (display was block) {
            //Defaultly testi has display:none property.
            testi = make testi display
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

That task was not working for me. How to add css properties?? Didn't found errors. Here's the code:

```
jQuery('.menu_toggler').click(function () {
    var scrnwidth = jQuery(window).width();
    var display = jQuery('.mobile_menu_wrapperr');
    var testi = jQuery('.main_header');
    if (scrnwidth <= 761) {
        if (display.css("display") === "block") {
            testi = testi.css("display" == "none");
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `testi.css("display", "none");` is the correct syntax (or `testi.hide()`) - although I'd suggest you do this logic in CSS using media queries instead. See my answer for more details about that

Comment: Try this to check element is visible or not. and based on this hide element.      `if (display.is(":visible")) 
     testi.css('display','none');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

syntax is incorrect

```
 testi = testi.css("display" == "none");
```

correct syntax

```
 testi = testi.css("display","none");
```

or

`testi.hide();`

Answer (score 2):

To make a div show you can just use:

```
$('#name-of-div').show();
```

Or if you want to hide a div then ... drum roll ..

```
$('#name-of-div').hide();
```

And then if you just want to toggle between show/hide then ..

```
$('#name-of-div').toggle();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax for hiding the element isn't quite right, you need to supply the rule and value as separate arguments:

```
testi.css("display", "none");
// or testi.hide()
```

That being said I'd strongly suggest you don't use JS for this and instead use CSS media queries:

```
.main_header {
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 760px) {
  .main_header {
    display: none;
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might not need jquery...

```
document.querySelector('#div').style.display = 'block' // 'none'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.menu_toggler').click(function () {
    var scrnwidth = jQuery(window).width();
    var display = jQuery('.mobile_menu_wrapperr');
    var testi = jQuery('.main_header');
    if (scrnwidth <= 761) {
        if (display.attr("style")=="display:block") {
            testi = testi.attr("style","display:none;");
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct the Syntax :

```
jQuery('.menu_toggler').click(function () {

    var scrnwidth = jQuery(window).width();
    var display = jQuery('.mobile_menu_wrapperr');
    var testi = jQuery('.main_header');
    if (scrnwidth <= 761) {
        if (display.css("display") === "block") {
            testi = testi.css("display","none");
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```